# Simple .htaccess redirect within the same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A bit of a newbie question, how can I redirect a URL like this one: http://example.com.ar to  http://example.com.ar/pictures/ using .htaccess ?

or would it be easier to make a rule that searches the entire request URL and adds a /pictures/ when not found?

I have tried:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com.ar [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.ar/pictures/ [R=301,NC]
```

But it didn't work :/

Comment: Provide that what you have tried yet for to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward. You would have found hundreds of existing examples...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /pictures/ [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely worked, also thank you for your advice on http servers host configuration, I will look into that now